# EzPublish render searchHits in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, ezpublish

I have the following code to retrieve the main menu on my EzPublish 5.4 site:

```
$query = new LocationQuery();
    $query->query = new Criterion\LogicalAnd(
        array(
            new Criterion\ContentTypeIdentifier( $this->getTopMenuContentTypeIdentifierList() ),
            new Criterion\Visibility( Criterion\Visibility::VISIBLE ),
            new Criterion\Location\Depth(
                Criterion\Operator::BETWEEN,
                array( $rootLocation->depth + 1, $rootLocation->depth + 3 )
            ),
            new Criterion\Subtree( $rootLocation->pathString ),
            new Criterion\LanguageCode( $configResolver->getParameter( 'languages' ) )
        )
    );
    $query->sortClauses = array( new Query\SortClause\Location\Depth(), new Query\SortClause\Location\Priority() );
    $main_menu = $searchService->findLocations( $query )->searchHits;
```

This works, I get all the results I expect and now I give this array to my Twig template:

```
{% for item in menu %}
<a href="#menuitemurl">Menu item title in current language</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Two questions:
1: how do I get the URL to this SearchHit to be rendered in Twig ? I have no clue where to get this, Google didn't help
2: How to get the title of the SearchHit in the current site's language? My site is multilingual, every item is available in both Swedish as English, but I somehow only get the English title with above code, even when I am on the Swedish version

Comment: why don't use knpMenuBundle for render twig? ezpublish using knpMenuBundle, its powerfull. https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle

Answer (score 0):

You could load the corresponding content objects like that :

```
$contentList = [];
foreach ( $searchService->findLocations( $query )->searchHits as $hit )
{
    $contentList[] = $this->contentService->loadContent( $hit->valueObject->contentInfo->id );
};
```

and pass `$contentList[]` it to the template. Then use it to get content full URL.

Or render contents in your templates based on content Id from your searchHits.